# sql server 2014 express connect database with promp install

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I'm a new in sql server express
I want create a database and table with prompt in windows.
but I don't understand how to login for create a database and table.

in oracle:

`connect`

`create user user identified by password;`

and then I could create tables

In sql server what is the equivalents istructions?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The command line utility to use with SQL Server is called sqlcmd. This article will get you started, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166559(v=sql.120).aspx.

Here's some more info about its options, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(v=sql.120).aspx.